# Rails - save model objects directly through browser URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently I have a `Stats` model with only one attribute: seconds

Is there a way to call the `create` action directly through the URL as oppose to saving it through `localhost:3000/stats/new/`?

I tried something along the lines of `localhost:3000/stats/create?seconds=100`, but that doesn't seem to be correct.

Comment: It is recommended that you do not create any model object via a get request. It can go horribly wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As opposed to the advice received already, you certainly *can* do what you want.

If Microsoft can make "Windows" with programming, I'm sure you can create an object directly from a URL request.

---

**GET vs POST**

The important thing to note is how the `create` method is [called](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions)...

```
POST    /photos photos#create   create a new photo
```

This is a `POST` request. It means that if you want to "load" this URL from your browser, you have to use the [`POST` HTTP verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)) -- which has to be explicitly defined.

--

**POST**

Whilst what you're asking *is* possible with the standard `POST` route, if you wanted to set your `seconds` explicitly, [you'll need to use `GET`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp):

> ... the query string is **sent in the URL** of a **GET** request:
>
> ... the query string is **sent in the HTTP message body** of a **POST** request:

Therefore, if you wanted to add one stat each time, you could use the following:

```
#app/views/....
<%= link_to "Add Stat", stats_path, method: :post %>

#app/controllers/stats_controller.rb
class StatsController < ApplicationController
   def create
      @stat = Stat.create seconds: "1"
   end
end
```

--

**GET**

If you wanted to do as you're asking, you'd have to set up a `GET` request for your `create` action:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :stats do
   get :create, on: :create
end
```

This will allow you to access:

```
url.com/stats/create?seconds=100
```

You'd gain access to `params[:seconds]` in your controller:

```
#app/controllers/stats_controller.rb
class StatsController < ApplicationController
   def create
      @stat = Stat.create stat_params
   end

   private

   def stat_params
      params.permit(:seconds)
   end
end
```

---

So to answer your question, *yes* it's possible, it's just a matter of how you want to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that you do not create any model object via a get request. It can go horribly wrong, But if you really want to create, here is how you do it.

`routes.rb`

```
resources :stats, except: [:create] do
    get "create", on: :collection
end
```

`stats_controller.rb`

```
def create
   stats = Stats.create(stats_create_params)
end


private

def stats_create_params
   params.permit(:second)
end
```

Comment: _It is recommended that you do not create any model object via a get request. It can go horribly wrong_ - explain please.

Comment: One can write a background job to just ping the url, and your objects would be created. It can populate your db unnecessarily, and you can get DOS attacks

Comment: i just wrap create `get` to [`protect_from_forgery`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection.html) filter, as like `post`.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I don't believe so. With how RoR is structured, you need a route to hit a controller#action and you have to create the new model there to be stored in your database. It's the rules of the framework and you have to follow it.

Comment: it's not a framework rules. It's a RESTful - [recommendation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer).

Comment: But isn't it a framework's decision to follow a RESTful style?

Comment: it's all about application design and architecture.  [*you certainly can do what you want.*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33718512/2057388)

Comment: After re-reading her post I think I mis-understood the question. I thought she meant she wanted to hit a url and have it create the object in the DB through some RoR magic without having to go through controller#action. It turns out she just want's to hit the create action with a url that reflects the same name.